# Is it a good practice to include all files in one .h file and include that file everywhere for AVR?

Tags: c, embedded, avr-gcc

Can I do like this

```
/*includeAll.h*/

#ifndef INCLUDEALL_H_
#define INCLUDEALL_H_ 1

#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#include "DataTypeDefs.h"

#include "timer_api.h"
#include "uart_api.h"
#include "RTC_PCF8563.h" 
#include "TWI_Master.h"
#include "ADC_LTC1859.h"
#include "spi.h"
#include "AT45DB161D_UART_AS_mSPI.h"

#include "Utilities.h"

#ifndef F_CPU 
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#endif

#include <util/delay.h>


#include <string.h>

#endif /* INCLUDEALL_H_ */
```

And include this includeAll.h file everywhere.
Everywhere means in all the project files.

Similar macro like  #define INCLUDEALL_H_ 1 has been used in all the other files.

I see that in compile time it takes very long.

Comment: You can, however it seems to eliminate some of the benefits of modular code, compiling modules and linking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aside from the compile time penalty, doing so makes changing/porting/refactoring of the code a lot harder.

I have the general rule that I keep dependencies at an absolute minimum. It doesn't take much work to include a missing header in the right place, and saves you a lot of headache later.

Answer (score 1):

You can user your `includeAll.h` as a [precompiled header](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Precompiled-Headers.html). I would recommend changing the extension to `.pch`.

Comment: How to do it in AVR Studio 5 IDE?

Comment: The question is taged as avr-gcc, do you have a link to the gcc documentation for avr?